# PHP mysqli Recent activity by date

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried a bunch of different ways to do this that other people have done but I can't quite get it. I have a database with a bunch of print job orders, and I have a print order TRACKER on my website. On the tracker page, I'd like to display the recent activity done by displaying all of the print jobs created in the last month.

I'm trying to do this without over complicating it also.

Here I just try to make an SQL query saying WHERE Date_Completed BETWEEN lastMonth && today. Here's one of the latest snippets that I've tried (not all of the code):

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$today = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$lastMonth = date_modify($date, "-1 month");
$result = $lastMonth->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

SELECT * FROM other_card WHERE  Date_Completed BETWEEN '$today' AND '$result' order by Date_Completed");
```

Any information is helpful! I know the variables are named a bit odd. Just been trying to get it to work.

Comment: What do you get when you execute your query?

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring the query instead like:

SELECT * FROM other_card WHERE  Date_Completed < '$today' AND Date_Completed > '$result' order by Date_Completed");

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate the dates in PHP. MySQL can do it for you:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ... Date_Completed BETWEEN now() - interval 1 month AND now()
```

This also takes care of some edge cases where PHP could be generating the dates at 11:59:59pm on the last day of a month, and the query doesn't actually executed until 00:00:01am next month.

Comment: Ah always something simple. I noticed it was tricky to get MySQL to get the datetime object, didn't think this could be done. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

1. Between works from smaller to bigger value, not opposite
2. You don't need between at all, just Date_Completed > some date will do.
3. On a side note, you should be using prepared statements, instead of adding value directly to query